# Parse Fast Infoset documents in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, fastinfoset

Is there a library which allows PHP to decode [application/fastinfoset](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/fastinfoset/) binary XML?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no PHP-library that does this. Can you hack around this by creating a tiny java-program that decodes/transforms the FI and call this from PHP?

I know this is a less-than-ideal solution, but this does seem to be uncharted territory.

https://fi.dev.java.net/how-to-use.html has some java-examples on how to handle FI.

As for bridging PHP and Java;

http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-java-bridge is supposedly good (though, site is down when I try),

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.java.php also have som information on integrating Java and PHP.

Alternatively, you can use probably use webservice or messaging to communicate between PHP and Java. (This is probably obvious.)